# HikariCP on AppEngine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, hikaricp

When deploying a Spring Boot application using HikariCP as the connection pool on Appengine, I get some errors related to database (threads), when performing some requests:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1008)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
```

Then I discovered that AppEngine only allow applications to create threads using its ThreadFactory. So I made sure to configure my Hikari to use AppEngine's Thread factory like the following :

```
DataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
try {
    final HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(applicationProperties.getDatasource()
                                                            .getDriverClassName());
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(applicationProperties.getDatasource()
                                                    .getUrl());
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername(applicationProperties.getDatasource()
                                                    .getUsername());
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword(applicationProperties.getDatasource()
                                                    .getPassword());

    dataSourceConfig.setRegisterMbeans(false);
    if (Objects.equal(ProfileResolver.getActiveCloudPlatform(env), ProfileConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_GCP)) {
        log.info("[GCP] Set 'com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.backgroundThreadFactory()' "
                    + "as the instance of the java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory");
        dataSourceConfig.setThreadFactory(ThreadManager.backgroundThreadFactory());
    }
    ds = new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
return ds;
```

It works on my local appengine (DevServer), But when deployed I get an exception at datasource initialisation, since Appengine's autoscaling modules doesn't allow the use of Background threads.

**Is it possible to keep the "autoscaling" ability while using HikariCP on AppEngine ?**

Answer (score 0):

The Java 8 runtime doesn't have the same restrictions around threads like prior versions of App Engine. For example, this [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet) uses HikariCP to connect to Cloud SQL, and works without a custom thread manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I remember using hikari with its default configuration at first, but I encountered the problem, I'm specifying in my question, as soon as I start getting lot of requests. I mean Hikari uses background threads and Appengine still have some restrictions in its execution environment when it comes to threads (in autoscaling mode)?

Comment: Are you using Java 7 or Java 8 runtime?

Comment: I m using java 8

Comment: According to the docs, the Java 8 run-time allows for background threads (I don't see anything to indicate auto-scaling matters): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#threads

Comment: So we agree that HikariCP should use ThreadManager API for its ThreadFactory? 
In this doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed you'll see that background threading isn't allowed in automatic scaling.

Comment: No, you can use HikariCP with default Java threads (like in the example I linked). The doc specifies that the ThreadManager is only necessary if you are calling an App Engine API from that thread (which Hikari shouldn't need to do).

Comment: Yes, but threads in appengine cannot outlive the request, I mean all threads must finish their work at within the request. But, in hikari we may have threads that are not related to a certain request, especially when creating new connections or removing idle ones.

Comment: I've also found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/yoaxc8I4Go0

Comment: Indeed the docs specify; "threads in app-engine cannot outlive the request"
But i checked and both HikariCP with normal threads and background threads work.
With the background thread enabled the application doesn't shut down after idle time, so the new variant is a great addition.

I think Google has to update the documentation with this new thread functionality...